# Objective-C Disabled iOS BLE Pairing Message

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is there anyway to disable the pairing message in iOS for a bluetooth device? The device I'm connecting to does not require any security and there is no pairing mechanism in place so having the message pop up is not needed. Any suggestions?

Comment: A BLE pairing message will only be displayed if a characteristic on the device requires security. The only way to avoid the pairing prompt is to change the characteristic definition on the device to remove the encryption requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To confirm Paulw11's comment above a Pairing prompt will be displayed in iOS when a device is connected and any type of encryption is requested during the connection or encryption is required when writing to a characteristic.

If the user clicks "Cancel" the encryption will not be enabled for the connection, but the connection will not be terminated. If you click "Pair" encryption will be enabled and the connection will also persist.

There is no way to listen or interact with the pairing prompt via the base iOS configuration through the CoreBluetooth Framework. I've talked with Apple about this and done lots of digging. There may be a way to do this through the MFI program, but obviously we can't talk about that.

Comment: Hi James, does that mean even user clicks "Cancel" the connection is still established? If so, how do we prevent unwanted connection?

Comment: Yes, the connection is still established after a user clicks cancel. We handled it by attempting to read a value back from the characteristic and if we didn't get a valid response within a set period of time we forced a disconnect.

Comment: Can Reestablishing the connection ask for the same prompt again or it wont.